# TagName in Kendo ListView in Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, kendo-ui, asp.net-core, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-listview

I have simple kendo listview:

```
@(Html.Kendo().ListView<SomeViewModel>()
    //...
    .TagName("div")
    //...
)
```

The question is, what `TagName` method does? Documentation says:

> The TagName of Kendo ListView for ASP.NET MVC used to create an
>   element which will contain all listivew items once the listview is
>   bound.

But when I'm changing it, absolutely nothing happens in output html, for example, I've changed it to `ul` and template was in `li` but it didn't create list of items.

So, why do we need `TagName` method, if it didn't work?